# Байты предваряют сериализованные данные

Tags: java, google-protobuf

Стоит задача реализовать обмен данными по TCP/IP с внешним сервисом.

Согласно документации сервиса, сообщение строится следующим образом:

Поля заголовка (6 шт), предваряют байты сериализованной структуры сообщения (protobuf v2).

**Структура сообщения:**

[image: Структура передаваемого сообщения]

**В заголовке передаются поля:**

[image: Структура полей заголовка]

В заголовке все числа передаются в Little-Endian.

Что касается формирования объекта PAYLOAD, там все достаточно прозрачно, есть  объект .proto с которого создается объект Message, добавляются параметры, сериализуется и передается в запрос.

Но что делать с HEADERом не понятно, каким образом они должны "предварять" байты основного сообщения и как в 2 байта запихнуть строку "12U3z" - не понятно.

Comment: Тут стоит задать этот вопрос непосредственно в поддержку этого самого сервиса. Потому что в приведенном виде это описание выглядит несколько бредово.

Comment: "12U3z" - похоже на ересь. В крайнем случае можно перебрать все 65536 вариантов значений в поле CODE и понять, чему все-таки равно  "12U3z" :)